# Как заставить второй фрейм отображаться только и только после нажатия кнопки на первом фрейме?

Tags: java, разработка-игр

Предположим я пытаюсь создать 3D шутер на языке Java (дальше - Ява). У меня есть экран входа (класс Fry) в игру и экран самой игры (класс Display). При запуске программы оба окна появляются одновременно. Вопрос: как сделать, чтобы сначала появлялось окно входа, а только потом, при вводе Никнейма и Пароля и нажатии на "Вход", открывалась сама игра?

Answer (score 0):

Есть много способов. Я предоставлю простой, через потоки. Поставь потоки таким образом. **(Если игра не онлайн, то делай всё так же, только без сессии).**

- Поток №1 главный, контролирует всё приложение. При старте запускает игры поток №1 и №2. После получения данных для сессии с потока №2, создаёшь сессию, запускаешь №3 поток, отправляешь сессию потоку №3.(Если игра  без возможности играть по сети,то просто запускаешь поток №3)
- Поток №2 хранит создаёт класса Fry,когда получены верные данные для входа передать данные для создания сессии в поток №1 и завершить поток №2. (Если игра  без возможности играть по сети, то просто отправляешь значение авторизации true)
- Поток №3 создаёт объект Класса Display(когда получена сессия) и держит сессию пока поток №3 не закроется .(Если игра  без возможности играть по сети, то ничего не держит)